# How to approximate a value from a formula

Tags: python, math

So I have one vector of alpha, one vector of beta, and I am trying to find a theta for when the sum of all the estimates (for alpha's `1 to N` and beta's `1 to N`) equals 60:

[image: \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{e^{\alpha_i(\theta-\beta_i)}}{1 + e^{\alpha_i(\theta-\beta_i)}} = 60]

```
def CalcTheta(grensscore, alpha, beta):
    theta = 0.0001
    estimate = [grensscore-1]
    while(sum(estimate) < grensscore):
        theta += 0.00001
        for x in range(len(beta)):
            if x == 0:
                estimate = []
            estimate.append(math.exp(alpha[x] * (theta - beta[x])) /
                            (1 + math.exp(alpha[x] * (theta - beta[x]))))
    return(theta)
```

Basically what I did is start from `theta = 0.0001`, and iterate through, calculating all these sums, and when it is lower than 60, continue by adding 0.0001 each time, while above 60 means we found the theta.

I found the value `theta` this way. Problem is, it took me about 60 seconds using Python, to find a theta of 0.456.

What is quicker approach to find this theta (since I would like to apply this for other data)?

Comment: Where do these estimates come from? Which of `alpha`, `beta`, and `theta` are the estimates? What is `x`? What do expressions like `alpha[x]` mean (are you *indexing* with `x`, *multiplying* by `x`, *constructing an estimate* based on a parameter `x`,...)? What does this have to do with [tag:irt]? (Incidentally, this question--in a slightly more abstract form--seems to be asking "how do I efficiently find a root of a univariate function." By itself it would likely be deemed off-topic here, but if you can supply a clearer statistical context we might be able to keep it open.)

Comment: x stands for the x-th item. Alpha is a list of values, beta is a list of values.

Comment: It is in the context of finding the ability needed to pass, given a  border value. Say we have 80 questions, and we need to have 60 correct, what is the estimated theta (ability) needed to pass? In this case the question difficulty and slope are given.

Comment: I hope this clarifies, sorry for the confusion. If you'd prefer, I also wrote down this function in R.

Comment: Thanks. The question now clearly asks about algorithms to find zeros of a [differentiable] univariate function (of $\theta$) in Python, so I will migrate this to SO where you are likely to get a broader range of solutions than here.

Comment: Thank looks a lot like a logistic regression. Running that would probably be a bit faster than brute forcing it.

Comment: How would you model that? The sum of all these logistic regressions should be 60.

Answer (score 2):

If you know a lower and an upper bound for *θ*, and the function is monotonic in the range between these, then you could employ a [bisection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_algorithm) to easily and quickly find the desired value.

Comment: Yes, I realized that is what I did in the end!